# Overfull hbox in align environment - how should I break lines?

Tags: align

I'm trying to create a logical argument, but I'm getting the error of overfull hbox.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{align*} 
P1\text{*}: & \quad \text{P1 is a mathematical abstraction of distance.} \\ 
P2\text{*}: & \quad \text{P2 is a statement regarding distances in the physical world.} \\
P3\text{*}: & \quad \text{The physical world requires a resolution to distinguish distance, while mathematics can use any resolution.} \\
C1\text{*}: & \quad \text{Therefore, Zeno's argument is flawed.}
\end{align*}
```

I want to split the line at the comma in the line "The physical world requires a resolution to distinguish distance, while mathematics can use any resolution.", but how would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: why are you using `align` (an AMS environment for aligned equations) if all you have is text?  wouldn't this be better as a `tabular` or even better as a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possibilities using `tabularx` or `itemize`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l<:X}
P1* & P1 is a mathematical abstraction of distance.\\
P2* & P2 is a statement regarding distances in the physical world. \\
P3* & The physical world requires a resolution to distinguish distance, while mathematics can use any resolution. \\
C1 & Therefore, Zeno's argument is flawed.
\end{tabularx}

\begin{itemize}
\item[P1*:] P1 is a mathematical abstraction of distance.
\item [P2*:]  P2 is a statement regarding distances in the physical world. 
\item[P3*:]  The physical world requires a resolution to distinguish distance, while mathematics can use any resolution. 
\item[C1:]  Therefore, Zeno's argument is flawed.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a `description` environment  and package `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font = \normalfont, labelwidth=1cm, leftmargin=!, itemsep=2pt]
\item[P1\textsuperscript{*}:] P1 is a mathematical abstraction of distance.
\item[P2\textsuperscript{*}:] P2 is a statement regarding distances in the physical world. distinguish distance, while mathematics can use any resolution.
\item[P3\textsuperscript{*}:] The physical world requires a resolution to distinguish distance, while mathematics can use any resolution.
\item[C1\textsuperscript{*}:] Therefore, Zeno's argument is flawed.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]